# Program for sending a message to email in Java

Tags: java, email, send

I created a program that sends files to email in Java. How to insert a timer that will automatically send mail every 2 minutes?
I think it could be through a timer, but if someone has a different way or encountered this or a similar problem, it would help me a lot.

Here's the code:

```
public class EMail {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SendEmail();

    }
    private static void SendEmail ()
    {
        final String username = "youremail@gmail.com";
        final String password = "password";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator()
        {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });
      
        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("youremail@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("youremail@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
            message.setText("PFA");

            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            String file = "C:\\Users\\Name\\UserData\\Logs.txt";
            String fileName = "Logs.txt";
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            message.setContent(multipart);

            System.out.println("Sending");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
    }
}
```

Comment: A thread with a Timer is suited for this. your send-email code isn't relevant for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.This code will enable you to send mails for every two minutes.

```
public class EmailHandler{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Thread emailSenderThread = new Thread(new EmailSender());
        emailSenderThread.start();

    }
    private static class EmailSender implements Runnable {

          private void sendEmail(){
          //Email sending logic Impl
          }
          @Override
          public void run() {
               for(;;){
                   sendEmail();
                   try {
                       Thread.sleep(120000);//Thread is sleeping for 2 minutes
                   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                       System.out.println(e);
                   }

               }
           }

      }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Timer` and `TimerTask` which are java util classes used to schedule tasks in a background thread

Example (You can add this to `main` method):

```
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

  @Override
  public void run() {
   SendEmail();
 }
};
Timer timer = new Timer("MyTimer"); 
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 500, 2000);
```